# python subprocess custom return code

Tags: python, subprocess

I'd like to return a value from a python subprocess call corresponding to the kind of error returned. E.g.:

test.py

```
RETCODE_OK = 0
RETCODE_THING_1_FAILED = 1
RETCODE_THING_2_FAILED = 2

def main():
    return RETCODE_THING_2_FAILED

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I'm calling it with subprocess, like so:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('python test.py', shell=True)
>>> proc.communicate()
(None, None)
>>> proc.returncode
0
```

I'd like this to return whatever was returned in main(), in this case 2. I've also got other stuff in the stdout and stderr streams, so I can't just `print RETCODE_THING_2_FAILED` and get the stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes uses exit codes, not return statements.
You should use `sys.exit(STATUS)` rather than `return STATUS` statement:

```
test2.py:
---------
import sys

def main():
    sys.exit(RETCODE_THING_2_FAILED)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

interpreter:
------------
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('python test2.py')
>>> p.communicate()
(None, None)
>>> p.returncode
2
```

This is because the process is actually closing/exiting, not returning a value to another function.